# Exporting pandas dataframe to csv; auto capitalizing

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe (df) which has a column comprised of either TRUE or FALSE.

When exporting into csv, TRUE and FALSE becomes True and False. I have tried to export it as a string, but that keeps happening.

This is my code for exporting as a string:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply('="{}"',format)
```

Comment: Are you sure your DataFrame column is a string column and not a boolean column? It works for me to just export the DataFrame if the column is a column of strings.

Comment: I don't think it is Boolean. The dataframe column was created by importing a csv file.

Comment: Pandas may be automatically converting it for you. What does df['col'].dtype return?